# Keep file name when uploading to a FileField in Django

Tags: django, django-models

In one of my models, I have an ImageField (which is basically a FileField, but with a couple extra tidbits). I specify an upload location with the following:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='path/to/directory'
```

When I save an image to this ImageField, I use the following:

```
with open(original_image.path) as image_file:
    image_temp = ContentFile(name=os.path.basename(original_image.path), content=image_file.read())
    my_model.image = image_temp
```

Unforturnately, this renames the file from what it was originally to 'directory.' Now this wouldn't be so much of a problem, but I need to keep the original extension of the image. How can I keep the original file extension?

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of how much I have understood your question, try changing your function.

```
def upload_image_path(instance, filename):
    new_filename = random.randint(1,910209312) # or use whatever you want
    name, ext = get_filename_ext(filename)
    final_filename = '{new_filename}{ext}'.format(new_filename=new_filename, ext=ext)
    return "chapters/{new_filename}/{final_filename}".format(
            new_filename=new_filename, 
            final_filename=final_filename
            )# this will be your location


def get_filename_ext(filepath):
    base_name = os.path.basename(filepath)
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(base_name)
    return name, ext


  image = models.FileField(upload_to = upload_image_path, null = True, blank = True)
```

Hope this will work fine.